# How can I construct a rotationally symmetric energy eigenstate for a particle on a ring?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry, schroedinger-equation

The energy eigenstates for a particle on a ring are $\psi_m(\phi) \propto e^{im\phi}$, which are two-fold degenerate. A general energy eigenstate is any linear combination of these, which I can write as $a\psi_m + b\psi_{-m}$. These eigenstates are in general not rotationally symmetric. How can I construct a rotationally symmetric energy eigenstate for an arbitrary energy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. If it $\psi(\theta)$ is independent of the angle $\theta$, then it is an eigenstate of the $L= -i\partial_\theta$  with eigenvalue $0$, and so an eigenstate of $H=L^2= -\partial^2_\theta$ with eigenvalue $E=0$.

Comment: Note, however, that any eigenstate of $L$ has uniform probability density.  That might sort of count as rotationally symmetric in a weaker way.

Comment: Of course. Don't know where my head was with that one... My intuition was telling me that for something with circular symmetry, there must be a state that is rotationally symmetric for any energy, which is clearly false mathematically.